# Keep blowing 3 amp fuse at furnace

Tags: air-conditioning

Keep blowing 3 amp fuse on the furnace control board. At the furnace I am getting 240 on the 60 amp breaker at the furnace and I am getting 120 on 30 amp breaker breaker side.

Comment: 240 and 120 are voltages, and since they are standard in a US system, that doesn't mean much. A 3A fuse is also much smaller than the 30A and 60A breakers, so this is not (at least directly) a real system overload. Questions: How often does the fuse blow? Any pattern (e.g., startup, after running for a certain amount of time, etc.)? Most important: **Manufacturer/model #**.

Comment: Can you understand the schematic of the furnace to see what the correct configuration is suppose to be? Furnaces should have diagnostic and specification info on them.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please?